# How to use the Backgrounder jQuery plugin as a slideshow?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying tu use the [jQuery Backgrounder Plugin](https://github.com/bigfolio/jQuery-Backgrounder) as a slideshow but doesn't quite work. I'd really appreciate any kind of help at all. Thanks. Here's what I've got so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="my_background">
   <img src="/img/main/home.jpg" />
   <img src="/img/main/home-2.jpg" />
</div>
```

**jQuery call:**

```
$(function() {
      setInterval( $('#my_background').backgrounder({element : '#content-bg'}) , 5000 );
    });
```

**jQuery plugin**

Changed line

```
var img = $(this).children('img').first();
```

to

```
var img = $(this).children('img').next();
```

Once every 5 seconds it should switch the image but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: might not be what you're looking for, but you can do this with backstretch quite esaily http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: Thanks for the link Max, but unfortunately I can't use the backstrech plugin to fill a div and not the entire body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, without having to modify the plugin-code:

http://jsfiddle.net/WZ3TL/

**HTML**

```
<div id="my_background"></div>
<div id="content-bg"></div>
​
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    //list of images
    var images = [
        'http://flickholdr.com/1200/600/landscape/bw',
        'http://flickholdr.com/1200/600/landscape/2'
    ];

    function rotate(){

        //get first images from the list
        var img = images.shift();
        //put it a the end of the list again
        images.push(img);

        //put image in source container
        $('#my_background').html('');
        $('<img/>').attr('src', img).appendTo($('#my_background'));

        //call backgrounder (again)
        $('#my_background').backgrounder({
            element: '#content-bg'
        });
    }

    //initial call
    rotate();

    //call in interval
    setInterval( rotate, 1000 );
});
```

​

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm a beginner with jQuery and don't have the time I'd like to study it so this helped me out tremendously!

Comment: I'd like to award you some of my bounty for this answer. How do I do that?

Comment: you're welcome. no need for a bounty here :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work